# AWS Sagemaker can't deploy SKLearn model : Access Denied when calling the CreateBucket operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

**My SKLearn estimator is:**

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn
FRAMEWORK_VERSION = "0.23-1"
script_path = 'scikit-iris.py'
sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
    train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    output_path='s3://My-bucket/sklearn-iris-artifacts',
    hyperparameters={'max_leaf_nodes': 30})
```

**Fitting model:**

```
sklearn.fit({'train': train_s3})
```

But when i am trying to deploy model i am getting Access Denied when calling the CreateBucket operatio.
Could someone help me why it is trying to create bucket when already output_path is present(Arifacts location).

**Below is my deployment code:**

```
predictor = sklearn.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                           instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge")
```

Comment: Most likely the role that you running SageMaker as, doesn't have permissions to create a bucket. Go to IAM find the role used by SageMaker in your case and make sure it has appropriate permissions to S3.

Comment: I have already give the output path where my artifacts are stored. Could you please explain me why it is tying to create new bucket?                                                                       And when I deployed model using sagemaker inbuilt algorithm it worked fine. without any error.

Comment: Which version of the SageMaker Python SDK are you using? Can you try upgrading and see if the issue persists? `pip install --upgrade sagemaker`